# sppring data hadoop map reduce job thrwoing no class found exception

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, spring-data

I am trying to run a map-reduce job using spring data appache hadoop with hadoop version 0.20.0 and 
spring - hadoop version 1.0.

i am getting No class found exception at running map task.Please help.

```
    Apr 3, 2013 4:30:13 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19b8e059: startup date [Wed Apr 03 16:30:13 GMT+05:30 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:13 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:14 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:14 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@f9da4fc: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,hadoopConfiguration,wordCountJob,wordCountJobRunner]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:15 PM org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobExecutor$2 run
INFO: Starting job [wordCountJob]
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient configureCommandLineOptions
WARNING: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat listStatus
INFO: Total input paths to process : 1
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Running job: job_201304011410_0007
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:16 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO:  map 0% reduce 0%
Apr 3, 2013 4:30:27 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Task Id : attempt_201304011410_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.icloud.WordMapper
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:809)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.icloud.WordMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:807)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: what is the command you are using to run ?i think you are missing jar file having com.apple.icloud.WordMapper class

Comment: i am using maven install to create jar file...so i think the class shoud be inside the jar file